# how can i array this outup like coordinates

Tags: python, new-operator

I have an output like this

```
array([[-10], [-23], [-12]])
```

But i need it to be like this

```
 array([-10,  -23, -12])
```

Already tried np.reshape().

thank you

Comment: `array.reshape(-1)` or `array.flatten()` or `array.ravel()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to flatten a numpy array. Here are a few:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[-10], [-23], [-12]])

np.reshape(x, -1)  # array([-10, -23, -12])
x.reshape(-1)  # array([-10, -23, -12])
x.flatten()  # array([-10, -23, -12])
x.ravel()  # array([-10, -23, -12])
```

Comment: Hi, it sayys " 'list' object has no attribute 'flatten(ravel)' "

Comment: That means you are not making your list a numpy array. Use `np.array(LIST)`, and then can use any of the methods. But `np.reshape(x, -1)` should work just fine on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Using `flatten`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[-10], [-23], [-12]])
a.flatten()
```

Output:

```
array([-10, -23, -12])
```

**Note** : Per your comments if you have just a list as follows:

```
lst = [[-10], [-23], [-12]]
```

You need to first convert it to a numpy array (per your question), you can do this by:

```
a = np.array(lst)
```

then flatten it by:

```
a.flatten()
```

Comment: Hi, it sayys " 'list' object has no attribute 'flatten' "

Comment: @neto333 : I added this to my answer. Hope it helps